# Is it possible to cure drunkenness?

Tags: medical-science, alcohol

Is there a possibility in science where they'll be able to make something that will counteract or defeat drunkenness in such a way that if you get drunk you can drink something to make it go away real quick? Like curing a fever or a cough? Do you think it will be possible, if not now, but in the future, for something(maybe a drug) to alter the human body and remove the cause of drunkenness? So you can theoretically drink all you want, afterwards you'll drink something and then the drunkenness will go away?

Comment: Hello there, would there be a proper StackExchange for this question? I thought this would be the site for questions like this but it seems I have to put in a source where I am skeptical of the claim(that science can cure drunkenness or intoxication), but the thought of it came from my mind alone. I tried looking at Google to see if there's a related article but I couldn't find one.

Comment: The closest articles I could find were about questions if coffee can help make you sober: [Can drinking coffee help a person sober up?](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/drinking-coffee-when-drunk-makes-sober.htm) and [Does Coffee Sober Up a Drunk?](http://chemistry.about.com/od/foodchemistryfaqs/f/Does-Coffee-Sober-Up-A-Drunk.htm), I don't know if these are considered notable though.

Comment: One last comment, I'm aiming specifically for inducing sobriety and eliminating drunkenness from a person instead of a cure for the hangover.

Comment: Concrete claims that a quick googling uncovers: Iomazenil and Dihydromyricetin.